# Angular 4 extend and implement

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing

I have a class Hero which needs to extend GoogleCharts class. I also need to implement OnInit to get the some data from params.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Just like this:

```
export class Hero extends GoogleCharts implements OnInit {...
```

If GoogleCharts already implements OnInit you should call `super.ngOnInit();` before doing other stuff in your ngOnInit method.

Like this:

```
interface OnInit {
    ngOnInit: () => void;
}

class GoogleCharts implements OnInit{

    ngOnInit() {
        //does some stuff here
    }

}

class Hero extends GoogleCharts implements OnInit{

    ngOnInit() {
        super.ngOnInit();
        //do my stuff here
    }

}
```

Comment: thank, you that worked. It seems the problem that if I have onInit in GoogleCharts implementing onInit in Hero will overwrite the onInit from GoogleCharts. Do you have any ideea how I can solve this?

Comment: I improved my answer. Remember you don't need to call `super.ngOnInit()` if you don't want it to be executed. In your case you probably have to call it because otherwise GoogleCharts wouldn't initialize correctly.